# recyclerview highlight just one item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i have recycler view and i highlight the item when i click in it , the problem is i can highlight many item , i wont just one item , when i click into item is highlight and when i click another item is highlight too

this is MyAdapter

```
public class ScreenRecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScreenRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context context;
int image_list[];
ImageView image_view_screen_item;

public ScreenRecyclerAdapter(int[] image_list, Context context){
    super();
    this.image_list = image_list;
    this.context = context;}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen_items, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(image_list[position]).into(holder.image_view_screen_item);
     holder.list_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         }
     });
   }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return image_list.length;
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image_view_screen_item , back;
    RelativeLayout list_row;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image_view_screen_item = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantImageView);
        list_row = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row);
        list_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    list_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5d5d5"));
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, ImagePager.class);
                    context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }}}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set two different click listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define a list of RelativeLayouts for your adapter which contains every rows:

```
List<RelativeLayout> items;
```

Then in your onBindViewHolder method, add:

```
items.add(holder.list_row);
```

Now add a method to your adapter like this:

```
private void makeAllWhite() {
    for(RelativeLayout item : items) {
        item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
}
```

Finally before this line:

```
list_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5d5d5"));
```

call:

```
makeAllWhite();
```

Your final code should be like this:

```
public class ScreenRecyclerAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScreenRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    int image_list[];
    ImageView image_view_screen_item;
    List<RelativeLayout> items;

    public ScreenRecyclerAdapter(int[] image_list, Context context){
        super();
        this.image_list = image_list;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen_items, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;}
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        items.add(holder.list_row);
        Picasso.with(context).load(image_list[position]).into(holder.image_view_screen_item);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return image_list.length;
    }
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image_view_screen_item , back;
        RelativeLayout list_row;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image_view_screen_item = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plantImageView);
            list_row = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_row);
            list_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        makeAllWhite();
                        list_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d5d5d5"));
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, ImagePager.class);
                        context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void makeAllWhite() {
        for(RelativeLayout item : items) {
            item.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but rows ? what is " rows" ?  cannot reslove !

Comment: the app is crash here 
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.example.todo.imagepagertest.ScreenRecyclerAdapter.makeAllWhite(ScreenRecyclerAdapter.java:68)

Comment: You have to initialize items list in your constructor. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the same thing here. There are multiple solutions to it but what I found most convenient is storing a copy of the view (or viewholder, both work) and in every onClick event check if the view (or viewholder) is same, if not then change the background of the previously selected view and set the new background for the selected item else use `return ;`

Comment: I do not have the code right now but I overrode..? the onTouch listener on the RecyclerView in the MainActivity instead of the ViewHolder inside the Adapter class.
Assume you are using a list item onclick listener (with View view, int position), now you check if this view is same as the globally stored view in your activity. worked like a charm for me. xyz extends Activity{ View globalView = null; onClickLisntener(View view, int pos ...){
if (globalView == null) {view = globalView} else if (globalView == view){ return;} else {globalView.setBackground(null); globalView = view;} }

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, you're setting the `OnClickListener` for the `ViewHolder`, which is basically representing every item. The binding (of data, design, events, etc.) is happening in `onBindViewHolder` according to the position in the dataset. So just move your event implementation from the constructor of `ViewHolder` to `onBindViewHolder`.

It may be irrelevant because it seems that your dataset isn't modified by the event, but if it does, don't forget to call [notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) after modification.